# Django test print or log failure

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a django_rest_framework test (the problem is the same with a regular django test) that looks like this:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class APITests(APITestCase):

    # tests for unauthorized access
    def test_unauthorized(self):
        ...
        for api in apipoints:
            response = self.client.options(api)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

I have a url that fails, the terminal shows this:

> FAIL: test_unauthorized (app.misuper.tests.APITests)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/alejandro/...",
>
> line 64, in test_unauthorized
>
> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN) AssertionError: 200 != 403

Ok, how can I know which url failed the test? I am iterating through all urls that require login, that is many urls, how can I print the one that failed the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple quick-fix, you can pass the `apipoint` in the third parameter of the assertion method:

```
>>> from unittest import TestCase
>>> TestCase('__init__').assertEqual(1, 2, msg='teh thing is b0rked')
AssertionError: teh thing is b0rked
```

In the spirit of unit testing, these should really be each different test methods rather than only one test method with the loop.  Check out [nose_parameterized](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized/) for help with making that more DRY.  You'll decorate the test method like this:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized

@parameterized.expand(apipoints)
def test_unauthorized(self, apipoint):
    response = self.client.options(apipoint)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

The decorator will generate different test methods for each endpoint, so that they can pass/fail independently of one another.

Although this package has `nose` in the name, [it's also compatible with other runners](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized#compatibility) such as `unittest` and `py.test`.